# (PHP/MYSQL) Fatal error: Class 'STemplate' not found

Tags: php, mysql, class, xampp

my php script have this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'STemplate' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\AdultWatch\index.php on line 20

i use xampp in windows, I do not know why this error is appearing....

my `index.php/config.php`(inclued) [File Here](https://gist.github.com/coalitos2/47eaec38f52ea52d99df54ead3c19ed2)

Comment: Where are you including the class STemplate?? The error pretty much tells you what is going wrong..

Comment: yes... look the config file.. in github

Comment: the link:
https://gist.github.com/coalitos2/47eaec38f52ea52d99df54ead3c19ed2

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `assign()` function of `STemplate` class on Line No: 67 but forgot to declare `STemplate` class before it.

```
STemplate::assign($field, strip_mq_gpc($config[$field]));
```

Class declaration syntax should be

```
$STemplate = new ClassName();
```